# MemoryStream Capacity Problem. Is there another stream class like memorystream, not memorytributary?

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, memorystream

I'm trying to serialize a big data. I'm getting an error OutOfMemoryException when serialize data. I did some researches. I found some information that it is said that there is an error about MemoryStream. Because memorystream supports 2GB data size. It has Capacity as Integer. I found another class can be used instead of memory stream. It is called MemoryTributary. I tried this class. But it gave me really bad performance. Can I find a framework or another thing like memorystream for big data ?

I would like to share what I did shortly :

---

- Get Data From SQLServer
- Convert Data To A Structure
- Serialize Data
- Compress Data By Using LZ4 Algorithm
- Upload Data To Azure

---

- Get Data From Azure
- Decompress Data By Using LZ4 Algorithm
- Deserialize Data
- Use data for operation

---

I have some codes like below :

```
    public static Stream ConvertObjectToStream<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return null;
        var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
        try
        {
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            boisSerializer.Serialize(obj, mem);
            return new MemoryStream(mem.ToArray()); 
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            var mem = new MemoryTributary();
            boisSerializer.Serialize(obj, mem);
            return new MemoryTributary(mem.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static Stream ConvertObjectToStream(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return null;
        var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
        try
        {
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            boisSerializer.Serialize(obj, obj.GetType(), mem);
            return new MemoryStream(mem.ToArray());
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            var mem = new MemoryTributary();
            boisSerializer.Serialize(obj, mem);
            return new MemoryTributary(mem.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static T ConvertStreamToObject<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
        var o = boisSerializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
        return o;
    }

    public static object ConvertStreamToObject(Stream stream, Type type)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
        object o = boisSerializer.Deserialize(stream, type);
        return o;
    }

    public static Stream CompressStream(this Stream stream, LZ4Level lz4Level = LZ4Level.L00_FAST)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var settings = new LZ4EncoderSettings { CompressionLevel = lz4Level };
        LZ4EncoderStream target = LZ4Stream.Encode(ms, settings);
        stream.CopyTo(target);
        target.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        return new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
    }

    public static Stream DecompressStream(this Stream stream)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Position = 0;
        LZ4DecoderStream source = LZ4Stream.Decode(stream);
        source.CopyTo(ms);
        source.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        return new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());

    }

public async Task UploadValueToContainer<T>(string containerName, string blobName, T obj)
    {
        Stream stream = Core.Tools.Helpers.ConvertObjectToStream(obj).CompressStream();
        CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        if (!container.Exists()) throw new Exception($"{containerName} Container has not been found.");
        CloudBlockBlob blobData = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        await blobData.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }

    public async Task<T> DownloadValueFromContainer<T>(string containerName, string blobName) where T : new()
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        if (!container.Exists()) throw new Exception($"{containerName} Container has not been found.");
        CloudBlockBlob blobData = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        if (!blobData.Exists())
        {
            return new T();
        }

        try
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await blobData.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
            return Core.Tools.Helpers.ConvertStreamToObject<T>(ms.DecompressStream());
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryTributary();
            await blobData.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
            return Core.Tools.Helpers.ConvertStreamToObject<T>(ms.DecompressStream());
        }
    }
```

Comment: also if you need to, use a memory mapped file, and a stream that can support it

Comment: I want to store 2GB data for serialization. Sorry, I didn't know xy problem. I said my solution, because I don't know that I'm not true or false. @mjwills

Comment: @TheGeneral I looked at memory mapped file now. It sounds great. It can be worked. I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Your main issue is that you are using your streams not as streams, but as arrays. From what I can see you don't even need a memory stream. If you are creating you serialized data why not directly serialize into the compression stream, and then feed the compression stream into the network stream. If you are reading your data you should feed the input network stream, into the decompression stream and this one into your deserialization. This way regardless how large your data is you would use a constant amount of memory of some kilobytes or megabytes (depending how large your buffers are).

Comment: For example, your deserialization should be something like this: `using (var networkStream = await blobData.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms))
{
 using (var decompressStream = LZ4Stream.Decode(networkStream))
 {
  object o = boisSerializer.Deserialize(decompressStream, type);
  return o;
 }
}`. As you can see there is no need to copy your data around multiple times.

Comment: @ckuri Thank you. You are right, I didn't try this. I separated codes into methods for code readability. Maybe I should merge methods to a single method. I will try what you said. For now I found something that is working. I used FileStream. It works for big data. And really It has the same performance than memorystream. I don't know how it is. Because I don't know how stream works in deep.